# As keyword with tablename alias in hive not working

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Unable to use as keyword for tablename alias  in HIVE ql

```
select a.day , a.buyer , b.name ,b.age ,b.id, a.work , a.year 
from tracker AS  a ,caller   AS b ;
```

gives

> mismatched input 'AS' expecting EOF near 'tracker'

Comment: why not just `select a.day , a.buyer , b.name ,b.age ,b.id, a.work , a.year from tracker a ,caller b `

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.day , a.buyer , b.name ,b.age ,b.id, a.work , a.year from tracker a ,caller b ;
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

The normal alias assignment with 'AS' keyword as used in some other RDBMS is not supported in PIG. I guess Rony's solution should work fine.